# How do I append the occurrence of a field using awk?

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, gawk

I am trying to append a number to a record that indicates how many times a particular value has occurred in a particular column within a file.  For example, let's say my file looks like this:

```
John,Guitar
John,Vocals
John,Piano
Paul,Bass
Paul,Vocals
George,Guitar
George,Vocals
Ringo,Drums
```

What I would like is to output a file that looks like this:

```
John,Guitar,1
John,Vocals,2
John,Piano,3
Paul,Bass,1
Paul,Vocals,2
George,Guitar,1
George,Vocals,2
Ringo,Drums,1
```

How do I achieve this in awk?  I would also be open to an answer using a shell script, or sed, as I'm just guessing that awk might be a good way of handling this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ $0=$0 OFS (++a[$1]) }1' file
```

The output:

```
John,Guitar,1
John,Vocals,2
John,Piano,3
Paul,Bass,1
Paul,Vocals,2
George,Guitar,1
George,Vocals,2
Ringo,Drums,1
```

---

The same with `print` operator:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }{ print $0,(++a[$1]) }' file
```

Comment: more of the same :) `awk -F"," '$0=$0","++a[$1]' file`

Comment: By the way, the `BEGIN` construction is usually unnecessary.  `awk {$++NF=++a[$1];print}' FS=, OFS=, file` is all you need here.

Comment: @jthill, *the BEGIN construction is usually unnecessary* - that's pretty subjective opinion

Answer (score 2):

With awk:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {print $1,$2,++counter[$1]}' file
```

Output:

```
John,Guitar,1
John,Vocals,2
John,Piano,3
Paul,Bass,1
Paul,Vocals,2
George,Guitar,1
George,Vocals,2
Ringo,Drums,1
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with awk

```
awk '{b=$0;sub(",.*","");$0=b","++c[$0]}1' infile
```